# attachement SendinBlue Api with nodejs

Tags: node.js, api, loopback4, sendinblue

i want to use Sendinblue api with my lb4 application to send mails
but i have some difficulties in attachment , can i get a clean  example
for  linking  sendinblue api V3 with loopback4 (nodejs)  thanks

Answer (score 1):

I followed the steps mentioned in their [reference docs](https://developers.sendinblue.com/reference#sendtransacemail) and got the below script working!

```
var request = require("request");

var options = {
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://api.sendinblue.com/v3/smtp/email',
  headers: {
    accept: 'application/json',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'api-key': 'API-KEY'
  },
  body: {
    sender: {name: 'Your Name', email: 'youremail@gmail.com'},
    to: [{email: 'recipient@gmail.com', name: 'Recipient name'}],
    attachment: [
      {
        url: 'http://personal.psu.edu/xqz5228/jpg.jpg', // Should be publicly available and shouldn't be a local file
        name: 'myAttachment.jpg'
      }
    ],
    htmlContent: 'This is a test Content',
    subject: 'This is test Subject'
  },
  json: true
};

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);

  console.log(body);
});
```

Though you haven't stated what issue you are facing exactly with the attachment but I am thinking it might have to do with the **attachment url** **not being absolute url and instead a local file**. If that's the issue, then I would suggest you to convert the attachment to base64 and then pass it following their reference document.

Please let me know if it helps!
Thanks